# Revolution Slider (jQuery) - is there a way (api) to stop video on slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

Is there a way to pause video placed on revolution slider slide programatically (from javascript)? From [documentation](http://clapat.ro/themes/creative/doc/rev-documentation.html#!/publicapi) it seems public API does not offer this function, only function to pause slider.

My case is that, I need to stop slider video, when some button, which starts another video is pressed.

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solutiom looking into revolution slider source code, to see how they internally use youtube API.

Youtube player object is stored within each slide video caption in data('player')

Example:

**Slider html markup**

```
<div id="mySlider" class="fullwidthbanner">
<ul>
    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <li id="slide1" data-fstransition="fade" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="10" data-masterspeed="300">
        <div class="caption sfb video" data-x="700" data-y="112" data-speed="500" data-start="1300" data-easing="easeOutExpo" data-nextslideatend="true" data-autoplay="true" data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="true">
            <iframe allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx?rel=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" width="448" height="267" id="slide1-video"></iframe>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript to stop embedded video in slide:**

```
// get player object
var player = $('#slide1 .video').data('player')
// now use yt api on player object to stop video, play video or whatever you want.
player.stopVideo();
```